QGIS - Identify Features Tool increase area of HTML response
Using QGIS 3.34.8 to connect to a WMS Server showing data of all registered geological boreholes in the german state of bavaria. Using the identify feature tool gives detailed information about the borehole data as a HTML response.
Trouble is, in the identify results dialog the area to show the html response is realy small, so that only a fraction of the data is shown, making it nearly impossible to use:

When i try "Print selected HTML response" and save the print output as a pdf i can see all of the data i am missing, only then it's static data:

Does anybody know a way to increase the area for the html response in the identify results dialog?
PS: If anybody wants to try for themselves, the wms server is available via: https://services.bgr.de/wms/geologie/gbl/ the data i am refering to is called Bohrungen. You'll need to zoom in on germany, specifically bavaria (southeastern most state of germany) to see the boreholes pop up from scales 1:100.000 and lower.

I suppose it's not your service?  If it were you might you could but an open in new window link into the GetFeatureInfo request response.    As a workaround you can use the debugging window to capture the actual request sent and open it in a browser.  For example like: https://boreholemap.bgr.de/boreholefeatureinfo/rest/by/header/__?featureId=BIS-BY_5920BG015232

To add to @nmtoken's comment, once you identify a feature and see the request logged in the debugging window, you can right-click the request to open it directly in your browser.

Nice! Definitively a huge step forward. Now i can at least access the data.
Is there any way to automate the process, e.g. Catch the request via python and automatically open a new browser windows showing the url?
